# multiple OR condiitons in a WHERE Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, latitude-longitude

I am in a situation where I need to gather data for certain lat lon data points within a 100m square distance. I am currently running a query as below which works fine for fewer locations. The query below for 15 data points take about 10 minutes to run, but this approach is not scalable with more data points. I ran a similar query with 4000 lat lon data points  ( relating to 4000 locations on US map) and the query would take 30 hours to run. I know where statement scans through the entire table row by row which is why the query runs for really really long. Even if I select fewer required columns the query takes long time to run. Do any of you have a better approach to accomplish this. Please advice.

```
            create table crt1
as
select * from masterdata
where
(round(device_lat,4) >= 33.7306 and round(device_lat , 4)  <= 33.7316 and round(device_lon,4) >= -117.8364 and round(device_lon , 4) <= -117.8354) or 

(round(device_lat,4) >= 37.927 and round(device_lat , 4)  <= 37.928 and round(device_lon,4) >= -122.517 and round(device_lon , 4) <= -122.516) or 

(round(device_lat,4) >= 30.2711 and round(device_lat , 4)  <= 30.2721 and round(device_lon,4) >= -97.7544 and round(device_lon , 4) <= -97.7534) or 

(round(device_lat,4) >= 33.0673 and round(device_lat , 4)  <= 33.0683 and round(device_lon,4) >= -117.2642 and round(device_lon , 4) <= -117.2632) or 

(round(device_lat,4) >= 34.8271 and round(device_lat , 4)  <= 34.8281 and round(device_lon,4) >= -82.3011 and round(device_lon , 4) <= -82.3001) or 

(round(device_lat,4) >= 32.9258 and round(device_lat , 4)  <= 32.9268 and round(device_lon,4) >= -96.8311 and round(device_lon , 4) <= -96.8301) or 

(round(device_lat,4) >= 45.0917 and round(device_lat , 4)  <= 45.0927 and round(device_lon,4) >= -93.4272 and round(device_lon , 4) <= -93.4262) or 

(round(device_lat,4) >= 36.0214 and round(device_lat , 4)  <= 36.0224 and round(device_lon,4) >= -115.0853 and round(device_lon , 4) <= -115.0843) or 

(round(device_lat,4) >= 47.2156 and round(device_lat , 4)  <= 47.2166 and round(device_lon,4) >= -122.2351 and round(device_lon , 4) <= -122.2341) or 

(round(device_lat,4) >= 32.2492 and round(device_lat , 4)  <= 32.2502 and round(device_lon,4) >= -110.8845 and round(device_lon , 4) <= -110.8835) or 

(round(device_lat,4) >= 32.286 and round(device_lat , 4)   <= 32.287 and round(device_lon,4) >= -110.9753 and round(device_lon , 4) <= -110.9743) or 

(round(device_lat,4) >= 36.8477 and round(device_lat , 4)  <= 36.8487 and round(device_lon,4) >= -119.7911 and round(device_lon , 4) <= -119.7901) or 

(round(device_lat,4) >= 36.0842 and round(device_lat , 4)  <= 36.0852 and round(device_lon,4) >= -79.8363 and round(device_lon , 4) <= -79.8353) or 

(round(device_lat,4) >= 39.0612 and round(device_lat , 4)  <= 39.0622 and round(device_lon,4) >= -77.1245 and round(device_lon , 4) <= -77.1235) or 

(round(device_lat,4) >= 32.8389 and round(device_lat , 4)  <= 32.8399 and round(device_lon,4) >= -117.1629 and round(device_lon , 4) <= -117.1619) or 

(round(device_lat,4) >= 61.1948 and round(device_lat , 4)  <= 61.1958 and round(device_lon,4) >= -149.9061 and round(device_lon , 4) <= -149.9051);
```

Comment: This is just completely unscaleable, any way you slice it. What you're looking for are the MySQL GIS extensions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html

Comment: Index the table properly and use separate selects with a union all between them. Also as an aside, the ROUND function is going to kill index usage, if you don't need that perform the round n the input, not on the query.

Comment: How about creating a temp table with the information of the rounded latitude and longitude values first then run your query against the temp table

Comment: Actually why are you even bothering to round?

Comment: @bobby - because the lat lon values are sometimes 5 digits and for simplicity purpose I wanted to just round it off.. do you think eliminating the round function might reduce the time for running

Comment: Its worth giving it a go, I doubt "round" costs much in compute time but because you are calling it so many times it may be worth removing it and seeing what the difference is

Answer (score 1):

First: create an index on `masterdata(device_lat)` and another on `masterdata(device_lon)`

Second, recast each line of this query as:

```
(device_lat >= 32.8389 and device_lat <= 32.8399 and 
 device_lon >= -117.1629 and device_lon <= -117.1619)  or ...
```

Your use of `round(lat,4)` has defeated your ability to use indexes for the search, which makes it very slow indeed: it has to scan your table multiple times.

If you happen to be be dealing with GPS data, or you happen to be using a spherical-earth approximation for distances, the `round()` function gains you nothing in precision. The actual precision of global positions is about four decimal places, and more digits of precision will neither help nor hurt your accuracy.

If you understand the terms Universal Transverse Mercator Projection or perhaps Lambert Projection, then you actually know a lot more about the precision of your data than your question indicates, and you should probably use that knowledge.

Actually, truth be told, you should recast this like so:

```
 SELECT m.* 
   FROM masterdata AS m
   JOIN (
        SELECT radius AS 0.0005
        ) AS radius
   JOIN  (  /* make a virtual table of your bunch of centerpoints */
        SELECT 33.7311 AS lat, -117.8359 AS long
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 37.9275, -122.5165
        UNION ALL
        SELECT somelat, somelon
        UNION ALL ...
   ) AS points
     ON m.device_lat >= points.lat - radius
    AND m.device_lat <= points.lat + radius
    AND m.device_long >= points.long - (radius / COS(RADIANS(points.lat)))
    AND m.device_long <= points.long + (radius / COS(RADIANS(points.lat)))
```

This will get you a good result as efficiently as possible. It will adjust your `radius` value for longitude searching to correct for the fact that longitude lines are closer together far from the equator. And it lets MySQL optimize.

**EDIT**

I just noticed your 100 meter square requirement, which I will interpret as a bounding box of +/- 50 m on the ground.  (You're nearing accuracy limits here.)

A degree of latitude is 111045 meters, so  you need a radius value of (50.0/111045.0) which happens to be about 0.0004503.  The value you have shown in your question, 0.0005 is more like a 111 meter square.

Here's some background. http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/

Comment: Thank you Ollie Jones. This is really helpful. I will try to work on some of those points. Yes I was trying to get a 100M square box  (+-50meters) and was trying to make approximations using 0.0005 which I know yields to 111 meters.But that is fine from my task accuracy purpose. The biggest issue is the run time of the query. Hopefully with the above suggestions let me see if I can reduce the time. Thanks again!